# Call a method to be used in all activities in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make this functionality. In the menu button, there is exit function. I have around 6 activities, they all have this menu button function. I have created a ExitDialog class , then it could be used in all activities, now the problem is I do not know how to do it

```
public class ExitDialog extends Activity {

    // public ExitDialog(SessionOverview sessionOverview) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    // }

    // dialog to quit application
    public void dialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(null);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.to_quit);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.hint);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new okListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new cancelListener());

        builder.create().show();
    }

    class okListener implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    class cancelListener implements
            android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: first you have to clear about java concepts

Answer (score 0):

```
yourActivity extends ExitDialog;
```

and make calling class method as `public` or `protected`

now use method in yourActivity

Comment: Although theoretically possible, it is not something I would recommend. There's really no need to extend ExitDialog when you could instead just pass it a context.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your class really does not need to extend `Activity`. Instead, pass it a context.

Also, when the cancel option should just close the dialog, you can pass `null` as the onClick behavior and dismissing the dialog will be the default action.

```
public class ExitDialog {

    private Context context;
    public ExitDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void dialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.to_quit);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.hint);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new okListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
        builder.create().show();
    }

    class okListener implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this inside an activity:

`new ExitDialog(this).dialog();`

Answer (score -1):

write this in your other Ativities:

```
 ExitDialog dlg = new ExitDialog();
 dlg.dialog;
```

This creates a Object of ExitDialog. And through this variable (dlg) you can call the dialog method.

Comment: The AlertDialog builder needs a context. And it should be `dlg.dialog();`.